# Symfony functional testing repository - Doctrine error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony

I am trying to test a repository - as described in the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html). Whenever I try to run that test, I get the error:

> Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\SimpleObjectHydrator::$class

I've tracked down the line that throws the error, and in my case, this would be:

```
public function testCountAuthAttemptsByUser()
{
    **// THROWS THE ERROR**
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array(
        'username' => 'testuser'
    ));

    $securitySessions = $this->em
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:SecuritySession')
        ->countAuthAttemptsByUser($user)
    ;

    $this->assertEquals(BruteForceAvoider::$timeLockFailAmounts, $securitySessions[1]);
}
```

The rest is the exact same as in the symfony example- I've looked up everything but cannot find a solution. What does this error say? May there be an error within the User entity? Testing a custom repository method is working fine, but when calling the "findOneBy", it fails..

Comment: can you show the user class ?

Comment: It is pretty huge.. I think the problem does not lay in the user class because when testing the repository method directly by passing the username and join everything there, it works. Why would the findOneBy method throw such an error..

Comment: You can show part of it. the namespace, the entity name, the mapping for username ... just to be sure